# TF2 - static_transform_publisher - Extrapolation into the future

Tags: ros, moveit, tf2, planning-scene, static-transform-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a couple of static_transform_publishers from the TF2 package running. How is it possible that a node complains about extrapolating into the future, when it tries to lookup a transformation from a random element to the static one? In my [understanding](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Migration), the static-transforms should be valid for all eternity, so why would you complain about timing issues?

A further explanation about my setup:

I have 2 Kinects and I am using those in my moveIt setup to create the Octomap.
As explained [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/192871/tf-extrapolation-into-future-wierd-chain/), moveIt complains about extrapolation into the future while looking up a transform from my robot to the cameras.

My first solution was to write a python node, which would handle all the publishing instead of seperate static_transform_publishers from the old TF. There, I could date the transformations back in time to avoid those issues.

Now I read about the static transforms in TF2 and implemented all the camera transformations like this:

```
<node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="camera_top_base_link_1" args="0 -0.045 0 0 0 0 1 /camera_top/camera_top_link camera_top/camera_top_rgb_frame  " />
```

Still, moveIt is complaining

```
[ERROR] [1411130239.665581579]: Transform error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1411130239.663295803 but the latest data is at time 1411130239.541714906, when looking up transform from frame [finger_2_link_0] to frame [camera_top/camera_top_depth_optical_frame]
[ERROR] [1411130239.997648183]: Transform cache was not updated. Self-filtering may fail
```

But running ``rosrun tf tf_echo /finger_2_link_0 camera_top/camera_top_depth_optical_frame` has no problems and tells me the transforms moveIt couldn't find?

Thanks in advance,

Rabe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193046/tf2---static_transform_publisher---extrapolation-into-the-future/) by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 683 on 2014-09-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2014-09-19**:
Have you tried reducing `static_transform_publisher`'s publishing frequency from the current rate (1000Hz)? I would suggest that you decrease that frequency to 10Hz or even 1Hz.

**Comment by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on 2014-09-19**:
Why is there a rate at all? My understandin was that it was "static" as in "published once"? Anyway, I can't even set the rate in the current way it is implemented, see the file [here](https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/blob/hydro-devel/tf2_ros/src/static_transform_broadcaster_program.cpp)

**Comment by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on 2014-09-19**:
I also tried various rates with the old implementation of tf, which didn't change anything either

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2014-09-19**:
@Rabe Sorry, I made a mistake when reading your `static_transform_publisher` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect static transform isn't the problem here.

The problem here is that MoveIt is requesting a very recent transform, and your system hasn't published that transform yet. Note that the time differential here is pretty small, about 0.12 seconds, so it's most likely just a processing delay somewhere in your system.

I would start by running `rosrun tf tf_monitor` to inspect the transform delays in your system, and then follow up by looking through the [tf Troubleshooting guide](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Debugging%20tf%20problems)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I understand it, tf2's `static_transform_publisher` does indeed publish a single static transform, instead of tf's method of sending it continuously. However, users can still work with tf, even though it uses tf2 under the hood. To that end, I don't really know how MoveIt! works internally, but if it's using tf and not tf2, then my guess is that somewhere within the inner workings of tf/tf2, the transform is getting sent out repeatedly in the style of tf. Try using the [original tf static_transform_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher), which lets you set a broadcast rate in ms, and see if that fixes the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-09-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1